# Calculating from Degrees to Decimal and Inverse formula

Tags: gis

The formula to convert from Degrees to Decimal is:

```
Decimal= SIGN* Degrees+(Dec. Degrees)/60
```

Where if SIGN=South or West, then SIGN=-1

But if I have Decimal value, how can I got SIGN, Degrees and Dec. Degrees values ?

As example if Decimal = 50 and Dec. Degrees = 90, I got result 51.5

```
 51.5 = 50 + 90/60
```

But trying to calculate inverse I got formula:

```
 51.5 = X1+ X2/60
```

Can not catch how get 2 vars X1 and X2 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to convert from `Decimal Degrees` (DD) to `Degrees,Minutes,Seconds` (DMS) and vice-versa.

```
// Decimal Degrees to Degrees,Minutes,Seconds
D = floor(DD);
M = floor((DD - D) * 60);
S = round((DD - D - M/60) * 3600);

// Degrees,Minutes,Seconds to Decimal Degrees
DD = D + M/60 + S/3600;

// calculations for your case above
DD = 51.5
D = floor(51.5) => D = 51
M = floor((51.5 - 51) * 60) => M = floor(0.5 * 60) => M = 30 
S = round((51.5 - 51 - 30/60) * 3600) => S = 0
// so 51.5 DD = 51° 30' 0'' DMS
```

If you want to keep the decimal part for seconds (for example `32.15` instead of `32`) as well you just have to remove the `round` call.

EDIT:
Regarding your values above **90 minutes** is actually **1 degree and 30 minutes**.
You can test the calculations yourself on [this page](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal)

Comment: Not sure, that is actually lat / lan calculations. Could you please give salvation for my example  :  51.5 = X1+ X2/60
?

Comment: Added the calculations for your value and added a page where you can test yourself.

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).